# problem with filtering data from 2 tables in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have 2 tables Project and Plan which has below feeds:

**Project**

1. ProjectId
2. ProjectName
3. Status

**Plan**

1. PlanId
2. ProjectId
3. PlanName
4. Status

Each project can have Zero or more plans in the plan table.

I would like to get the list of all projects from the table with the count of plan against each project.

I have tried the below Linq query to join the table

```
var project=(from p in _dbContext.Projects
        join pl in _dbContext.Plan
            on p.ProjectId equals s.ProjectId 
        into temp 
        from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select new ReturnDto
        {
            ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
            ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
            PlanCount = "(Need the count of plans against the project)"
        }).ToList();
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you try pl.Count() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the list of all projects from the table with the count of plan

I think that you want to know for every Project the number of Plans that it has.

Whenever you have a one-to-many relation, and you want to get "Items with their zero or more subitems", like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, or in your case Projects with their Plans, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin)

I use the one with a parameter resultSelector to specify the results:

```
IQueryable<Project> projects = ...
IQueryable<Plan> plans = ...

var projectsWithPlanCount = projects.GroupJoin(plans,

    project => project.Id,       // from every Project take the primary key
    plan => plan.ProjectId,      // from every Plan take the foreign key to Project

    // parameter resultSelector: from every Project with its zero or more Plans, make one new:
    (project, plansOfThisProject) => new
    {
        // Select the project properties that you plan to use
        Id = project.Id,
        Name = project.Name,
        ...

        PlanCount = plansOfThisProject.Count(),
    });
```

Simple comme bonjour!